# Sort json hierarchy

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have JSON with following structure:

```
{
   "name":"Scorpiones",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Parabuthus",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Parabuthus schlechteri"
            },
            {
               "name":"Parabuthus granulatus"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Buthidae",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Androctonus",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "name":"Androctonus crassicauda"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"Androctonus bicolor"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

It is required to sort the elements by the name field at each level of the hierarchy. How can this be done with the help of JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` which returns an array contains all object keys, then you can simply sort that array.

```html
const getSortedKeys = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort();
}
```

And to go throw all your object nested keys you can use recursion:

```js
const trav = (obj) => {
    if(obj instanceof Array) {
        // go inside each object in the array
        obj.forEach(item => trav(item))
    } else if(typeof obj === "object") {
        // sort object keys
        let keys = getSortedKeys(obj);
        // do whatevery you want...
        
        // go the the next levels
        keys.forEach(key => trav(obj[key]))
    }
}
```